# pyqt closing a custom dialog in main window via mouse click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

Q. is it possible, dialog closes itself and return color name just when user clicked or double clicked color item
Below is working example (hopefully to demonstrate problem). clicking on canvas area will pop up color dialog. currently user has to select color and then hit 'OK' button, where as intent is complete when user click on color. Just wanted to save user time, one bit.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

colorsDict = { 'White': '0xFFFFFF','DarkGray': '0xA9A9A9','DarkSlateGray': '0x2F4F4F','LightSlateGray': '0x778899','DimGray': '0x696969','Gray': '0x808080','SlateGray': '0x708090','Black': '0x000000','DarkRed': '0x8B0000','Darkorange': '0xFF8C00','FireBrick': '0xB22222','Crimson': '0xDC143C','Salmon': '0xFA8072'}
def hexToQColor (h):
    h = h.lstrip('#') # general usage safety
    # h = h.lstrip('0x') # my use case
    if h.find('0x') == 0:
        h = h.split('0x')[1]
    rgb = tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2 ,4))
    return QColor(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2])
class FfmpegColorDialog(QDialog):
    """
        Custom FFMPEG Color Picker class
    """
    resized = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FfmpegColorDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # self.ui = uic.loadUi('ui/ffmpeg_colors.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle("FFMPEG Color Picker")
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.readPrefs()
        self.listWidget.setFlow(QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.listWidget.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
        self.listWidget.setGridSize(QSize(32, 32))
        self.listWidget.setSpacing(5)
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.itemDoubleClicked)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        # OK and Cancel buttons
        buttons = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, Qt.Horizontal, self)
        buttons.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        layout.addWidget(buttons)

    def readPrefs(self):
        """
        reading preferences from module for Data in UI
        """
        for each in colorsDict.keys():
            item = colorsDict[each]
            listItem = QListWidgetItem()
            listItem.setToolTip(each)

            listItem.setSizeHint(QSize(30, 30))
            color = hexToQColor(item)
            listItem.setBackground(QBrush(color))
            self.listWidget.addItem(listItem)
    def itemClicked(self,item):
        self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)
        # self.accept()
    def itemDoubleClicked(self,item):
        c = item.background().color()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)
        result = self.exec_()
        return(c,result==QDialog.Accepted)

    def getResults(self):
        if self.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
            # print (item.toolTip())
            return ( item.toolTip())
        else:
            return None
    def getUserColor(self):
        return (self.listWidget.currentItem().toolTip())
    @staticmethod
    def getFinalColor(parent=None):
        dialog = FfmpegColorDialog(parent)
        result = dialog.exec_()
        color = dialog.getUserColor()
        return(color,result==QDialog.Accepted)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    central_widget = None
    layout_container = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.layout_container = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout_container)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout_container.addWidget(GraphicsView())

class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.text = None
        self.createText()

    def createText(self):
        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        font = QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(40)
        self.text.setFont(font)
        self.text.setPlainText("Sample Text To Test")
        self.scene.addItem(self.text)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        r,ok = FfmpegColorDialog.getFinalColor()
        hc = colorsDict[r]
        rgb = hexToQColor(hc)
        self.text.setDefaultTextColor(rgb)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # dia = FfmpegColorDialog()
    # dia.show()
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc  just updated example with minimal code (hopefully) to test. huge thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just connect the clicked signal of the QListWidget to the accept slot of FfmpegColorDialog:

```
class FfmpegColorDialog(QDialog):
    """
        Custom FFMPEG Color Picker class
    """
    resized = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FfmpegColorDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # ...
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.clicked.connect(self.accept) # <---
        # ...
```